# Kotlin: the number of tens

Tags: arrays, kotlin, indexing

The description below is taken directly from the task I'm trying to solve. Apparently there are 4 tests that the program runs, but I don't know which inputs will be tested, so I'm trying to account for all of them.

> Write a program that reads a number and prints the tens in that
> number. Use indexes to solve this problem!
>
> Sample Input:
> 234
>
> Sample Output: 3

I came up with this code:

```
fun main() {
    val string = readLine()!!
    val digits = string.map(Character::getNumericValue).toIntArray()
    val len = digits.length 
    if (len == 2){
        println(digits[0])
    }
    else if (len == 3) {
        println(digits[1])
    }
    else if (len > 4)
        println(digits[-2])
    }
}
```

which gives me an error:

```
Compilation error
main.kt:14:1: error: expecting a top level declaration
}
^
main.kt:4:22: error: unresolved reference: length
    val len = digits.length
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE1: Changed `length` to `size` and fixed the missing `{`.

Comment: `main.kt:4:22: error: unresolved reference: length` - Kotlin array's dont have the field length in it for arrays. Instead it is `size`. So try `val len = digits.size`

Comment: You also forgot the opening `{` after the last `else if`.

Comment: @Sisir Just tried changing to `size` as suggested.
@Michael Thank you, just noticed it as well.

Currently getting the following error:
`Failed test #3 of 4. Runtime error

Error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -2 out of bounds for length 7

It passed 2 out of 4 tests, not sure why.

Comment: SO the compilation is through now. Now some issue in the logic of the function

Comment: Kotlin doesn't support negative indexing AFAIK. You can do something like `digits[digits.lastIndex-1]`.

Comment: Though it seems to me like you could simplify that entire `if / else if` block into `digits.getOrElse(digits.lastIndex-1) { 0 }`

Comment: @Michael

This `digits.getOrElse(digits.lastIndex-1) { 0 }` solved the riddle. Makes total sense. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 2):

**FINAL ANSWER**

```
fun main() {
    val string = readLine()!!
    val digits = string.map(Character::getNumericValue).toIntArray()
    val len = digits.size
    println(digits.getOrElse(digits.lastIndex-1) { 0 })
}
```

Thank you Sisir and Michael